# Issues running OAuthd instance

Tags: node.js, oauth, redis

I encounter problems when I try to run the OAuth instance in my directory.

(Based on https://github.com/oauth-io/oauthd) My Redis server is up and running, all is set. I followed all the instructions, doubled check everything and even tried a fresh re-install of node, redis and oauthd. Yet, every time I run the `oauthd start` command, I get the same output:

```
{ [Error: Cannot find module './build/Release/DTraceProviderBindings'] code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }
{ [Error: Cannot find module './build/default/DTraceProviderBindings'] code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }
{ [Error: Cannot find module './build/Debug/DTraceProviderBindings'] code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }
{ [Error: Cannot find module './build/Release/DTraceProviderBindings'] code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }
{ [Error: Cannot find module './build/default/DTraceProviderBindings'] code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }
{ [Error: Cannot find module './build/Debug/DTraceProviderBindings'] code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }
{ [Error: Cannot find module './build/Release/DTraceProviderBindings'] code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }
{ [Error: Cannot find module './build/default/DTraceProviderBindings'] code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }
{ [Error: Cannot find module './build/Debug/DTraceProviderBindings'] code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }
{ [Error: Cannot find module './build/Release/DTraceProviderBindings'] code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }
{ [Error: Cannot find module './build/default/DTraceProviderBindings'] code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }
{ [Error: Cannot find module './build/Debug/DTraceProviderBindings'] code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }
{ [Error: Cannot find module './build/Release/DTraceProviderBindings'] code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }
{ [Error: Cannot find module './build/default/DTraceProviderBindings'] code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }
{ [Error: Cannot find module './build/Debug/DTraceProviderBindings'] code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }
```

Do you have any suggestion on how to fix this ?

Thanks in advance !
^Q

Comment: Do you to fix problem?

Answer (score 0):

every time i run `hexo` command, i encounter following problems

`{ [Error: Cannot find module './build/Release/DTraceProviderBindings'] code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }
{ [Error: Cannot find module './build/default/DTraceProviderBindings'] code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }
{ [Error: Cannot find module './build/Debug/DTraceProviderBindings'] code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }`

After stackoverflowing it, i got the solution `npm install hexo --no-optional`.
As the hexo module have numerous dependencies, and rebuild it under an unstable network-environment would give rise to the same problem, there's no need to reinstall the whole module.
I found this module after seaching `DTraceProviderBindings` in hexo's folder.
this extension allows you to create native DTrace providers for your Node.js applications. That is, to create providers and probes which expose information specific to your application, rather than information about the node runtime. read more on [it's github page](https://github.com/chrisa/node-dtrace-provider).

---

Delete this optional module

`npm uninstall dtrace-provider`

Then no more error info.
But if you need to use this module, you can reinstall it

`npm install dtrace-provider`

of course it's optional.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem on my MacOS. After this steps:

1. Install Xcode
2. `rm -rf node_modules`
3. `npm install`

All work normal.

Answer (score 0):

I met this error in couple days then I found a way to fix it.
For anyone got this error on MacOS and using `yarn` instead of `npm`, please follow those steps:
- Install CodeX and open it, accept the term & privacy.
- Install node-gyp globally ( if `node-gyp` was installed, please try to remove it then add again).

```
yarn global remove node-gyp
yarn global add node-gyp
yarn
```