# Cannot find module dtrace-provider

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, restify

I have a simple nodejs application that is throwing `"Cannot find module './build/Release/DTraceProviderBindings'"`. I look it up online and it looks like that a lot of people are having the same problem when using restify on windows (which is my case, I'm using restify on windows 10). Apparently, [dtrace-provider is a optional module for restify](https://github.com/restify/node-restify/issues/100) and there is no version of it for windows. So, what I tried so far:

1. Update node to v6.2.0;
2. Uninstall all modules and run `npm install --no-optional`;
3. Uninstall only restify and run `npm install restify --no-optional`;
4. And my most desperate move npm install `dtrace-provider`.

Everything I tried where found on github issues, I've seen same error on OSX users with other modules. Not sure what else to try.

Note: This exception does not stop my application, not even prints the error on the console, I just notice that this was happening using the debugger, in other words, my application runs fine, but this keeps happening on the background.

List of other modules I'm using:

```
"dependencies": {
    "restify": "latest",
    "request":  ">=2.11.1",
    "cheerio":  ">=0.10.0",
    "xml2js":   ">=0.2.0",
    "botbuilder": "^0.11.1",
    "applicationinsights": "latest"
  }
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue. I hope somebody has a solution.

Comment: I've just tried to remove the whole `node_modules` directory and then `npm install --no-optional` and finally it seems that no error is thrown. Have you tried it?

Comment: Yeah, i tried that...keep happening for me

Comment: Your IDE, is it VS Code?

Comment: @BrunoBrant yes it is

Comment: Probably the reason why you're seeing the issue is that you have checked the "All Exceptions" option ticked (under the Debug menu, below "Breakpoints").

If I uncheck it, I no longer get the exception.

Comment: I posted an answer for the one has same issue with this, please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35703727/issues-running-oauthd-instance

Answer (score 13):

This worked for me after switching to Node 6.1 (and when re-installing node modules didn't work):

1. Install and save dtrace-provider

   ```
   $ npm install dtrace-provider --save
   ```
2. Delete 'node_modules' folder
3. Re-install node modules

   ```
   $ npm install
   ```

I found this thread before combining your attempts with another solution on the Github project issues for restify (https://github.com/restify/node-restify/issues/1093) and simplified best as possible.

Comment: I wish someone would update the dtrace-provider module - it simply spews out errors on MacOS when installing.

Answer (score 6):

I recently ran into this error as well on node `6.11.1`.
I ran `npm rebuild dtrace-provider` and that resolved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

The restify team followed an approach of trying to load the module by requiring it on a try/catch block. You should just ignore the exception.

Answer (score 2):

I had success with the following (elaborate) sequence:

1. Adjust my path to not have spaces
2. `rm -rf node_modules`
3. `rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/node-gyp/`
4. `npm cache clean --force`
5. `V=1 npm install -S dtrace-provider@0.8.8 --python=python2.7` (repeat this step, resolving as you go, until the install is completely successful … if it fails, check the version - I had rogue `dtrace-provider@0.6.0` building at one point)
6. `npm install`
7. At this point everything should have installed cleanly, and I was congratulating myself on a job well done. Then I executed my code and *still* got the `DTraceProviderBindings` error. The cause was nested dependencies with the wrong version of dtrace-provider (especially bunyan).
8. To confirm, do `npm list  | grep dtrace -B6`.
9. If there's anything lower than `0.8.8`, edit `package-lock.json`, following the method in [How do I override nested NPM dependency versions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15806152/how-do-i-override-nested-npm-dependency-versions). Replace `requires` with `dependencies` for `dtrace-provider` and update the version.
10. Back round to get everything clean: `rm -rf node_modules`
11. Then, again, `npm install --python=python2.7`

I had to iterate round `npm list` a few times because I thought I'd caught everything and I hadn't.

The key points were to use the required version of python, have a unix-friendly path, and hunt down all nested dependencies. The python version issues gave a big messy error, the space issue gave a much more missable error.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old issue but I wanted to comment on it in case anyone else has the same issue I had.

My issue was caused by having parentheses in my path. 
`/users/karlgroves/Dropbox (Personal)/foo/bar/bat/project...`

Moving the project to a path without the parens worked for me.
You'll need to wipe out `node_modules` and reinstall again.

Answer (score 1):

I recently ran into this error as well on node v8.8.1
as @Derek mentioned, I ran `npm rebuild dtrace-provider` and that resolved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

**tl;dr;** dtrace-provider utilized node-gyp which required python version >= 2.5 and NOT 3.5

I had this issue on OSX and found a post that showed using environment variable
`V=/Users/your_user/your_project npm i dtrace-provider`

This let me know that there was a dependency on `node-gyp` that was failing to build...Once I knew the issue was with this module was able to focus my attention at troubleshooting `node-gyp`.

This led to some log output indicating that my python version `3.5` was **unsupported** and it required version `>= 2.5`.

Went and downloaded python `2.7.x` and checked `/usr/bin/python 2.7.x` to ensure it was there.  Uninstalled the node module that was ultimately requiring this module, then used `npm cache clean` then reinstalled the module and this time it appeared to pick up the right python version to be able to build.

Hope this helps someone =)

Answer (score 0):

I have tried many suggestions but get the same error again.
Finally, I found the correct way to solve this question.
Go the [node.js website](https://nodejs.org/en/) and download the latest version of  **node.js pkg**.
After installed, reinstall your software, everything will be ok.

Answer (score 0):

i managed to get this working by running this command

```
npm install --python=python2.7
```