# Cannot find module './build/Debug/DTraceProviderBindings'

Tags: node.js, npm, dtrace

I know this question has been asked lots of times like
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37550100/cannot-find-module-dtrace-provider) and [here](https://github.com/trentm/node-bunyan/issues/216).
I have tried all suggestions on these links and more..
I tried installing the latest bunyan

```
sudo npm install bunyan@1.8.12 --unsafe-perm=true --allow-root
```

I installed and rebuilt latest dtrace-provider

```
sudo npm install dtrace-provider@0.8.7 --unsafe-perm=true --allow-root
sudo npm rebuild dtrace-provider@0.8.7 --unsafe-perm=true --allow-root
```

it built the module successfully.

```
+ NODE_GYP_STATUS=0
+ [[ 0 -ne 0 ]]
+ exit 0
  touch Release/obj.target/ndtp.stamp
npm WARN swaggerize-express@4.0.5 requires a peer of express@^4.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN tr-stack@1.0.0 No repository field.

+ dtrace-provider@0.8.7
```

In spite of that I am still getting this error:

```
Error: Cannot find module './build/Release/DTraceProviderBindings'
      at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:603:15)
      at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:529:25)
      at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:657:17)
      at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
      at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/yogeshsingh/TradeRev/code/tr-stack/node_modules/vogels/node_modules/dtrace-provider/dtrace-provider.js:17:23)
      at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:721:30)
      at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:732:10)
      at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:620:32)
      at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:560:12)
      at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:552:3)
```

node version and npm version are as follows:

```
 node: v11.6.0
 npm : 6.5.0
```